# exist db Dashboard "White Screen of Death"

Tags: nosql, jetty, xquery, exist-db

I was running an instance of exist-db on a server (3.7). I did a clean wipe of that installation, and decided to go with version 4.2 (I later tried 4.1 and the same thing happens). The installation went smoothly, I changed the default ports to 6000 and 8579 since the standard ones were already in use and everything seemed to work fine.

Afterwards, when trying to connect to the Dashboard like I did a million times, I got the eXist-DB splashscreen, but instead of going to the Dashboard, I got a "white screen of death" like in the picture.

The logs are empty, I get no error from the network, and I tried changing the version of Java, to no effect. I tried different ports and everything does the same thing. I can't seem to be able to access the Dashboard anymore.

Hope somebody has some idea what might be causing this.[image: white screen of death]

Comment: Is there the same white screen when you try with http://localhost:6000/exist/apps/dashboard/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the upgrading warning in the [release notes](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/) regarding dashboard? What version of dashboard was 3.x running, which version do you have now?

Have you tried to run this script in eXide or the Java Admin Client?

```
repo:install-and-deploy("http://exist-db.org/apps/dashboard", "http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/apps/public-repo/modules/find.xql")
```